# SVG rect border width in InkScape

Tags: svg, inkscape

My border is cut when I put rect at the good position.

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\"
   xmlns:cc=\"http://creativecommons.org/ns#\"
   xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"
   xmlns:svg=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"
   xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"
   xmlns:sodipodi=\"http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd\"
   xmlns:inkscape=\"http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape\"
   height=\"107\"
   width=\"75\"
   id=\"svg15578\"
   version=\"1.1\"
   inkscape:version=\"0.91 r13725\"
   sodipodi:docname=\"2c.svg\"
   inkscape:export-filename=\"G:\workspace\testspsy\src\main\webapp\img\cartes\2c---.png\"
   inkscape:export-xdpi=\"90\"
   inkscape:export-ydpi=\"90\">
  <metadata
     id=\"metadata15584\">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about=\"\">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource=\"http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage\" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id=\"defs15582\">
    <filter
       height=\"1\"
       width=\"1\"
       y=\"0\"
       x=\"0\"
       id=\"filter19349\"
       style=\"color-interpolation-filters:sRGB\"
       inkscape:menu-tooltip=\"Blend an image with its hue opposite\"
       inkscape:menu=\"Color\"
       inkscape:label=\"Blend Opposites\">
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19351\"
         in=\"SourceGraphic\"
         result=\"fbSourceGraphic\"
         values=\"180\"
         type=\"hueRotate\" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19353\"
         result=\"result1\"
         in=\"SourceGraphic\"
         values=\"1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 -0.2125 -0.7154 -0.0721 1 0 \" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19355\"
         values=\"0\"
         type=\"hueRotate\" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19357\"
         result=\"result3\"
         values=\"1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 \" />
      <feComposite
         id=\"feComposite19359\"
         operator=\"atop\"
         result=\"result6\"
         in2=\"result3\" />
      <feComposite
         k4=\"0\"
         id=\"feComposite19361\"
         result=\"result4\"
         in=\"result6\"
         k3=\"0.5\"
         k1=\"0.5\"
         k2=\"0.5\"
         operator=\"arithmetic\"
         in2=\"result6\" />
      <feBlend
         id=\"feBlend19363\"
         in=\"result4\"
         result=\"result2\"
         mode=\"normal\"
         in2=\"fbSourceGraphic\" />
      <feComposite
         k4=\"0\"
         k3=\"0\"
         k1=\"0\"
         id=\"feComposite19365\"
         result=\"result5\"
         k2=\"1\"
         operator=\"arithmetic\"
         in2=\"result2\" />
      <feComposite
         id=\"feComposite19367\"
         result=\"result5\"
         operator=\"in\"
         in2=\"SourceGraphic\" />
    </filter>
    <filter
       height=\"1\"
       width=\"1\"
       y=\"0\"
       x=\"0\"
       id=\"filter19349-1\"
       style=\"color-interpolation-filters:sRGB\"
       inkscape:menu-tooltip=\"Blend an image with its hue opposite\"
       inkscape:menu=\"Color\"
       inkscape:label=\"Blend Opposites\">
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19351-9\"
         in=\"SourceGraphic\"
         result=\"fbSourceGraphic\"
         values=\"180\"
         type=\"hueRotate\" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19353-8\"
         result=\"result1\"
         in=\"SourceGraphic\"
         values=\"1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 -0.2125 -0.7154 -0.0721 1 0 \" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19355-4\"
         values=\"0\"
         type=\"hueRotate\" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19357-8\"
         result=\"result3\"
         values=\"1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 \" />
      <feComposite
         id=\"feComposite19359-3\"
         operator=\"atop\"
         result=\"result6\"
         in2=\"result3\" />
      <feComposite
         k4=\"0\"
         id=\"feComposite19361-2\"
         result=\"result4\"
         in=\"result6\"
         k3=\"0.5\"
         k1=\"0.5\"
         k2=\"0.5\"
         operator=\"arithmetic\"
         in2=\"result6\" />
      <feBlend
         id=\"feBlend19363-0\"
         in=\"result4\"
         result=\"result2\"
         mode=\"normal\"
         in2=\"fbSourceGraphic\" />
      <feComposite
         k4=\"0\"
         k3=\"0\"
         k1=\"0\"
         id=\"feComposite19365-5\"
         result=\"result5\"
         k2=\"1\"
         operator=\"arithmetic\"
         in2=\"result2\" />
      <feComposite
         id=\"feComposite19367-3\"
         result=\"result5\"
         operator=\"in\"
         in2=\"SourceGraphic\" />
    </filter>
    <filter
       height=\"1\"
       width=\"1\"
       y=\"0\"
       x=\"0\"
       id=\"filter19349-3\"
       style=\"color-interpolation-filters:sRGB\"
       inkscape:menu-tooltip=\"Blend an image with its hue opposite\"
       inkscape:menu=\"Color\"
       inkscape:label=\"Blend Opposites\">
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19351-1\"
         in=\"SourceGraphic\"
         result=\"fbSourceGraphic\"
         values=\"180\"
         type=\"hueRotate\" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19353-82\"
         result=\"result1\"
         in=\"SourceGraphic\"
         values=\"1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 -0.2125 -0.7154 -0.0721 1 0 \" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19355-7\"
         values=\"0\"
         type=\"hueRotate\" />
      <feColorMatrix
         id=\"feColorMatrix19357-1\"
         result=\"result3\"
         values=\"1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 \" />
      <feComposite
         id=\"feComposite19359-4\"
         operator=\"atop\"
         result=\"result6\"
         in2=\"result3\" />
      <feComposite
         k4=\"0\"
         id=\"feComposite19361-9\"
         result=\"result4\"
         in=\"result6\"
         k3=\"0.5\"
         k1=\"0.5\"
         k2=\"0.5\"
         operator=\"arithmetic\"
         in2=\"result6\" />
      <feBlend
         id=\"feBlend19363-3\"
         in=\"result4\"
         result=\"result2\"
         mode=\"normal\"
         in2=\"fbSourceGraphic\" />
      <feComposite
         k4=\"0\"
         k3=\"0\"
         k1=\"0\"
         id=\"feComposite19365-9\"
         result=\"result5\"
         k2=\"1\"
         operator=\"arithmetic\"
         in2=\"result2\" />
      <feComposite
         id=\"feComposite19367-5\"
         result=\"result5\"
         operator=\"in\"
         in2=\"SourceGraphic\" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor=\"#ffffff\"
     bordercolor=\"#666666\"
     borderopacity=\"1\"
     objecttolerance=\"10\"
     gridtolerance=\"10\"
     guidetolerance=\"10\"
     inkscape:pageopacity=\"0\"
     inkscape:pageshadow=\"2\"
     inkscape:window-width=\"1366\"
     inkscape:window-height=\"716\"
     id=\"namedview15580\"
     showgrid=\"false\"
     inkscape:zoom=\"4.6045232\"
     inkscape:cx=\"31.25736\"
     inkscape:cy=\"52.230219\"
     inkscape:window-x=\"-8\"
     inkscape:window-y=\"-8\"
     inkscape:window-maximized=\"1\"
     inkscape:current-layer=\"svg15578\" />
  <g
     transform=\"matrix(0.33213028,0,0,0.33870772,-241.09242,484.58193)\"
     style=\"filter:url(#filter19349-3)\"
     id=\"g100781\">
    <rect
       y=\"-1428.8842\"
       x=\"727.75861\"
       height=\"310.81366\"
       width=\"222.23224\"
       id=\"rect4942\"
       style=\"display:inline;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.99291563;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1\"
       rx=\"10.582486\"
       ry=\"10.59592\" />
    <path
       d=\"m 838.87055,-1395.8791 c -9.77449,0.2122 -14.15744,11.2173 -6.91839,19.7633 1.04989,1.2465 1.15822,1.9619 -0.76458,0.7645 -4.87384,-3.2592 -14.21924,-1.1166 -14.69781,8.8473 -0.59114,12.2769 16.56286,15.8143 19.78372,2.7597 0.17004,-1.3774 1.28941,-1.346 1.01952,0.6091 -0.29368,5.3064 -1.95085,10.2661 -4.22863,15.1025 3.83908,0 8.12954,0 11.6202,0 -2.27768,-4.8364 -3.93495,-9.7961 -4.22864,-15.1025 -0.2699,-1.9551 0.84949,-1.9865 1.01953,-0.6091 3.22086,13.0546 20.37487,9.5172 19.78372,-2.7597 -0.47846,-9.9639 -9.82396,-12.1065 -14.69781,-8.8473 -1.92279,1.1974 -1.81448,0.482 -0.76458,-0.7645 7.23906,-8.546 2.8561,-19.551 -6.9183,-19.7633 0,-10e-5 0,0 -0.01,0 z\"
       id=\"path147-0-8-1-6-7-2-1-6-3\"
       inkscape:connector-curvature=\"0\"
       sodipodi:nodetypes=\"ccccccccccccccc\"
       style=\"display:inline;opacity:1\" />
    <path
       d=\"m 838.87055,-1150.2461 c -9.77448,-0.2123 -14.15744,-11.2173 -6.91838,-19.7633 1.0499,-1.2465 1.15822,-1.9619 -0.76458,-0.7645 -4.87385,3.2592 -14.21926,1.1166 -14.69782,-8.8473 -0.59115,-12.2769 16.56287,-15.8143 19.78373,-2.7597 0.17004,1.3774 1.28941,1.346 1.01952,-0.6091 -0.29368,-5.3064 -1.95084,-10.2661 -4.22863,-15.1025 3.83908,0 8.12955,0 11.6202,0 -2.27768,4.8364 -3.93495,9.7961 -4.22864,15.1025 -0.26989,1.9551 0.84949,1.9865 1.01953,0.6091 3.22086,-13.0546 20.37487,-9.5172 19.78372,2.7597 -0.47846,9.9639 -9.82396,12.1065 -14.69781,8.8473 -1.92279,-1.1974 -1.81447,-0.482 -0.76458,0.7645 7.23906,8.546 2.8561,19.551 -6.91829,19.7633 0,10e-5 0,-10e-5 -0.01,0 z\"
       id=\"path147-0-8-1-6-1-4-5-4-2\"
       inkscape:connector-curvature=\"0\"
       sodipodi:nodetypes=\"ccccccccccccccc\"
       style=\"display:inline;opacity:1\" />
    <path
       d=\"m 932.85251,-1167.8836 c 3.90977,-0.088 5.66301,-4.6738 2.76739,-8.2347 -0.42002,-0.5194 -0.46332,-0.8174 0.30583,-0.3185 1.94956,1.358 5.68771,0.4652 5.87915,-3.6864 0.23644,-5.1154 -6.6252,-6.5893 -7.91353,-1.1499 -0.0677,0.5739 -0.51579,0.5609 -0.40777,-0.2538 0.11747,-2.211 0.7803,-4.2775 1.69142,-6.2927 -1.54926,0 -3.09862,0 -4.64787,0 0.91112,2.0152 1.57394,4.0817 1.69142,6.2927 0.10801,0.8146 -0.33978,0.8277 -0.40777,0.2538 -1.28833,-5.4394 -8.14997,-3.9655 -7.91353,1.1499 0.19144,4.1516 3.92958,5.0444 5.87914,3.6864 0.76916,-0.4989 0.72585,-0.2009 0.30583,0.3185 -2.89562,3.5609 -1.14238,8.1463 2.7673,8.2347 9.9e-4,0 0,0 0,0 z\"
       id=\"path147-6-9-8-7-0-5-4-9-1\"
       inkscape:connector-curvature=\"0\"
       sodipodi:nodetypes=\"ccccccccccccccc\"
       style=\"display:inline;opacity:1\" />
    <path
       d=\"m 744.89757,-1379.0705 c -3.90978,0.088 -5.66302,4.6739 -2.7674,8.2347 0.42002,0.5194 0.46333,0.8175 -0.30583,0.3186 -1.94956,-1.358 -5.68769,-0.4653 -5.87913,3.6863 -0.23644,5.1154 6.62519,6.5893 7.91352,1.1499 0.0677,-0.5739 0.51578,-0.5608 0.40777,0.2538 -0.11748,2.211 -0.7803,4.2775 -1.69142,6.2927 1.54925,0 3.09861,0 4.64787,0 -0.91112,-2.0152 -1.57395,-4.0817 -1.69142,-6.2927 -0.10802,-0.8146 0.33977,-0.8277 0.40777,-0.2538 1.28833,5.4394 8.14997,3.9655 7.91353,-1.1499 -0.19144,-4.1516 -3.92959,-5.0443 -5.87915,-3.6863 -0.76915,0.4989 -0.72585,0.2008 -0.30583,-0.3186 2.89562,-3.5608 1.14238,-8.1462 -2.76729,-8.2347 -0.001,0 0,0 0,0 z\"
       id=\"path147-6-9-8-7-4-5-9-2-7\"
       inkscape:connector-curvature=\"0\"
       sodipodi:nodetypes=\"ccccccccccccccc\"
       style=\"display:inline;opacity:1\" />
    <path
       d=\"m 735.04976,-1382.2665 0.16008,-2.0284 c 0.50554,-6.2682 1.85071,-8.3828 9.48051,-14.9264 3.70419,-3.1719 4.91885,-4.737 5.08909,-6.5527 0.48512,-4.2827 -3.29971,-5.6194 -5.76486,-5.639 -3.19478,-0.029 -6.80938,1.9175 -5.08402,6.4418 l -3.58513,1.0743 c -0.72057,-4.2202 0.0209,-8.1792 3.37528,-9.9361 4.47982,-2.2909 10.22417,-1.3928 13.12457,2.2164 1.94936,2.4214 2.39476,5.7721 1.34905,8.3945 -3.0552,6.6989 -13.41895,9.6463 -14.27402,17.3973 l 11.45426,0 0,-4.3153 3.37527,0 0,7.9441 -18.70008,-0.07 z m 0,0\"
       id=\"path15-9-1-0-1\"
       inkscape:connector-curvature=\"0\"
       style=\"opacity:1\" />
    <path
       d=\"m 942.19966,-1164.6876 -0.16008,2.0285 c -0.50554,6.2681 -1.85071,8.3827 -9.48051,14.9263 -3.7042,3.1719 -4.91885,4.737 -5.08909,6.5528 -0.48512,4.2827 3.29971,5.6194 5.76486,5.639 3.19478,0.029 6.80938,-1.9176 5.08401,-6.4418 l 3.58513,-1.0743 c 0.72058,4.2201 -0.0209,8.1792 -3.37527,9.9361 -4.47982,2.2909 -10.22417,1.3928 -13.12457,-2.2165 -1.94936,-2.4213 -2.39476,-5.7721 -1.34905,-8.3944 3.0552,-6.6989 13.41895,-9.6464 14.27402,-17.3974 l -11.45426,0 0,4.3155 -3.37527,0 0,-7.9443 18.70008,0.071 z m 0,0\"
       id=\"path15-5-7-4-9-4\"
       inkscape:connector-curvature=\"0\"
       style=\"opacity:1\" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Funny. It's a property of the group which is inherited by the rectangle when ungrouping.

Comment: @Joce, I do not understand your comment. Have You an example of SVG code to make it work ?

Comment: I just tried to play around with your SVG file in inkscape and in the code. It looks like a clipping of the playing-card group, if you ungroup it the clipping is transferred to the rectangle. But I couldn't find the associated property in the code. A workaround I believe could be to add an empty transparent rectangle the same size as the page in the group, but I didn't try it as it's just a workaround...